# Avoid exponential values

Tags: c#, web-services, dto

I'm having some troubles with a dto in a webservice. The problem I have is a number, who comes in decimal format from the database, but when I use the webservice, the number appear like -3.2E-05

The structure of the dto in the c# code is:

```
 var dto = new RentabPorInstrumentoDTO
                              {
                                  RentabilidadHist = p.RENTABOLIDAD_HIST,
                                  RentabilidadHist = Convert.ToDouble(p.RENTABOLIDAD_HIST)
```

the number on the database is: -0.000032
the number received on the DTO is: -0.000032

my best regards!

Image is here: http://imageshack.com/a/img537/9963/RA8Ozf.png

Comment: That's just a string representation... they're the same value. It's not clear what you mean by "appear" anyway. Where are you seeing -3.2E-05?

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing the -3.2E-05 and I need to show the real number, without conversion. I have tried the .ToString() and the cultureInfo but nothing works.

If I try to use math.round() appears 0.

Comment: No, I asked *where* you're seeing -3.2E-05. That's a string representation, so there's no option of "without a conversion"... you're converting from a double to a string.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: yes, you are right. The problem appear when I invoke the webservice by SoapUI software and the WCF client.

I have attached an image up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the column defined as Double in your class, and probably also in your database. Doubles are Floats and will do things like this: Floats are not accurate (strange but true!). Redefine the member in the class to decimal and the column to decimal(18, x) where x is the number of decimal places you want and it'll be more predictable.

Note that -3.2E-05 is scientific notation for -0.000032: they are actually equal so you don't actually have a problem here, though using floats you will probably end up with one.